# What is the difference between standalone-full and standalonefull-ha?

Tags: wildfly

What is the difference between standalone-full and standalonefull-ha. what subsystems are not included in standalone-full-ha which are not avilable on  standalone-full?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't involve any programming related tasks.

Comment: Indeed, this is a sysadmin question IMHO. Plus, it was incorrectly tagged as [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka clustering; a data mining technique).

Answer (score 13):

**Full profile** includes **messaging** support (JMS - HornetQ, ...).

**HA profile** includes **clustering** support (Infinispan, failover, ...).

**Full HA** profile includes **both** of them.

Answer (score 2):

HA means High Avaibility. The standalone HA will start a second server process in slave mode which will become the master when the master server process stops.